# Smooth scroller based on mouse position (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, mouse, scroll

HI!

I would like to create a Smooth scroller based on mouse position. The idea is to create a outer div with a fixed width. The content is very wide and has to be scrolled to left or right, based on the mouse position. It would be great if the content is 'infinite' or 'endless'. The content is a very wide image that repeats 'seamelesly'.

Can anybody help me by creating this in jQuery?

Thanx in advance!

Alex

Comment: You can start writing something and let us know when you get stuck.

Answer (score 12):

You can set the image as the background of the `div` and animate the `background-position` with jquery. (*and because it got me interested, here is an implementation*)

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/72yhW/

**html**

```
<div class="backdrop">
    <div class="direction left"></div>
    <div class="direction right"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.backdrop{
    position:relative;
    height:300px; /*could be anything really..*/
    width:400px; /*could be anything really..*/
    border:3px solid #6699ff;
    background: url('YOUR IMAGE PATH GOES HERE') 0 0 repeat-x;
}

.direction{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
.left{left:0;top:0;}
.right{right:0;top:0;}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
    var x=0,
        y=0,
        rate=0,
        maxspeed=10;
    var backdrop = $('.backdrop');

    $('.direction', backdrop).mousemove(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var left = $this.is('.left');

        if (left){
            var w = $this.width();
            rate = (w - e.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 1)/w;
        }
        else{
            var w = $this.width();
            rate = -(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 1)/w;
        }
    });

    backdrop.hover(
        function(){
            var scroller = setInterval( moveBackdrop, 10 );
            $(this).data('scroller', scroller);
        },
        function(){
            var scroller = $(this).data('scroller');
            clearInterval( scroller );
        }
    );   

    function moveBackdrop(){
        x += maxspeed * rate;
        var newpos = x+'px '+y+'px';
        backdrop.css('background-position',newpos);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx Gaby! You helped me out and i'm very happy about the result!

Comment: @Alex, i made a change because the way i was calculating the offset was incorrect. Use the current code.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli this is awesome!! But how would you handle a long list of text context? <li>'s for example

Comment: @pcproff, that would require an entirely different approach. The current example works because background images are repeatable.. To repeat actual DOM elements you need to alter the DOM structure by moving elements around.. You might want to add a new Question to get as many people involved..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Hi there check this out. Just an idea of how to do it since ul>li's do not use background-position. http://jsfiddle.net/pcproff/NCrkE/2/

Comment: @pcproff, nice. good adaptation (*I first thought you wanted to make a repeating list, like the image..*). You might want to add a couple checks to stop it from scrolling when there are no more years to show.

Comment: You could also add `overflow:hidden` on the `.backdrop` to remove the scrollbars and remove the `width:100%` since it is a div.. [with alterations](http://jsfiddle.net/NCrkE/3/)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli this is awesome! the issue is detecting when the last <li> or the first <li> is in frame and stopping the animation :/

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/NCrkE/5/ No need to locate the elements. Just use the widths of the backdrop and the yearlist for min/max.. (*also set the width of the individual years to 9% as you have 11 years displayed..*)

Comment: This is a great piece of code but it depends on the window being a certain width. I use a lot of css 100% for <header> which is what this div is inside of. Works like a charm if the window is smaller.

Comment: @pcproff, actually it does not. That is why at the end of the script i recalculate the width of the backdrop when the browser is resized (*since it might affect the backdrop width, which is auto*)

Comment: I re size the preview window in jfiddle to allow for more years to be visible (by changing the for loop value to 20) and it just hops to a certain x coord. I am looking as to why. It seems if the window is left as is the code works fine.

Comment: that is because you set each `li` element to have a fixed percentage of its container.

Comment: Final update. A cleaned-up version at http://jsfiddle.net/NCrkE/35/ which works with any number of items. (*changes in JS/CSS*).

Answer (score 2):

There are two existing awesome jQuery plugins that do exactly what you seek:

1) http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller

2) http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/

Number 1 is more refined in that it has a smoother scrolling action and can optionally highlight the current hovered over item.

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin called [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) that does exactly this. It scrolls content smoothly and you can control it by hovering with the mouse over two hotspots (left and right, visible or invisible) inside the scroller. There is an option for infinite scrolling.