# "Not endless" background scroll with mouse position

Tags: javascript, background, mouse

I don't know JS too much and I'd like to add this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137535/1433139) to my site, however I don't want it to be endless. I want it to stop at certain limits or boundaries (min and max) in the x axis. How can I do that the simplest way?

Comment: Why not use the jQuery plugin mentioned in the post ? You will have to familiarize yourself with jQuery to do so, but thats probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I've tried doing `while (x =- 800)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm currently using the code, but it is "endless" and I don't want it to behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, use jquery it is easy to do with that. Suppose limit for your scroll is 800 (as you mentioned) then put following code in your js

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 800 ){
    return false;
  }
})
```

Your window will not scroll after top is 800px.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it didn't work. I think it's not the case that I need a "scroll" method or whatever it's called. Nor do I want the window to be scrolled. And it's not the y axis that I'm concerned about. Is the background image of the class `.backdrop` that I need to stop scrolling (in the x axis) after certain maximum and minimum value of the variable x.