# Jquery scroller based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have looked at [jquery hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136847/smooth-scroller-based-on-mouse-position-jquery/6137535#comment17947604_6137535) and this is all well and great but how can I use a list into this? The example that the previous user uses is all image backgrounds.

Im not sure if the  is in the right place.

```
<div class="backdrop">
 <ul id="year"></ul>
<div class="direction left"></div>
<div class="direction right"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72yhW/627/)

Comment: it cannot loop that way without using background-image and background-position.

Comment: Any other ways to move a ul,li via x coords?

Comment: use what you have. you're on the good way, but try harder.

Comment: Is it a css property I'm missing?

Comment: I ended up with something like this the reverse effect. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72yhW/647/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not change background position on `<ul><li>` I decided to use margin here if my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/pcproff/NCrkE/).