# content scrolls according to the position of the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'd like to know if there's a way of scrolling content according to the position of the cursor ? After hours of research found this carousel plugin http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/ however it doesn't seem like I can do free (diagonal) scrolling.

Comment: I think will help you. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136847/smooth-scroller-based-on-mouse-position-jquery

Comment: @csanonymus thanks for your reply, I found this link too during my research but it change the background position and this only on a newpos horizontally based. I tried to change it however however I dont really know how to adapt it to a div with another divs as content instead of background images.

Comment: Than have a look here : http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use jquery or javascript to get the mouse position of the client X and Y to pinpoint their position.

```
var x=event.clientX;
var y=event.clientY;

var windowHeight = window.innerHeight //and
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth
```

will also help.

```
if(x > windowWidth-400) {
   $('html, body')
    .animate({ scrollRight: 400 });
   }); 
}
```

I am pretty sire that will do the trick just do the same for y cords of your mouse and you should be good to go. :)