# Scrolling based on mouse position retaining click events in the foreground

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a very wide div within a smaller div. The inner div scrolls left and right depending on mouse position.

I adapted the code from this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137535/3656408

There are two transparent divs on top of everything, from which the position of the mouse is attained, which gives a speed at which to scroll.

The problem with this is anything underneath these divs is not clickable.

My div has a fixed width and height so I potentially could calculate the scroll speed from where the mouse is on the page ( ie. the page is 620px wide so I know 310 is half way )

Unfortunately my maths is terrible and I can't figure out how to convert my thought process into acceptable working code.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Heres how it currently figures out the rate at which to move the page...

```
$('.direction', backdrop).mousemove(function(e){
var $this = $(this);
var left = $this.is('.left');

if (left){
    var w = $this.width();
    rate = (w - e.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 1)/w;
}
else{
    var w = $this.width();
    rate = -(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left + 1)/w;
}
});
```

.. and you can see it in action here   http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/20years/index.html

Comment: If you can get this in a jsfiddle I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figure it out...

```
$( document ).mousemove(function(e){   //if mouse moves on page

if (e.pageX <= 620 && e.pageY <= 600){  //and if its not outside the extents of the div

    if (e.pageX <= 310){ //if its less than half way across
        rate = (310 - e.pageX)/50;
    } else { // if its more than half way across
        rate = -( e.pageX - 310)/50; 
    }

}

});
```